# Cycling through an array of form elements

Tags: javascript

I am returning form elements into a form from ajax.  I can count the number of elements returned, but I don't know how to cycle through them.  I need to be able to get the value of each element returned.

I am pretty sure this is a basic javascript thing that I just don't know.  The problem only looks more complicated with the Ajax.

My code looks like this:

```
    // The view page
    <html>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript">
    function calculateAlphaTotals(){
        var length = document.myForm["alpha[]"].length;
        alert( length ); // correctly outputs 3
        for( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
            try{
                alert( document.myForm["alpha[]"].value ); // HTML ObjectCollection 
                alert( document.myForm["alpha["+i+"]"].value ); // Object Required
            } catch( error ) { }
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="myForm" id="myFormId" method="post">
        <div id="ajaxOutputId"></div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    // The Ajax page:

    <input name="alpha[]" onchange="calculateAlphaTotals()" />
    <input name="alpha[]" onchange="calculateAlphaTotals()" />
    <input name="alpha[]" onchange="calculateAlphaTotals()" />
```

Comment: Thanks all!  I figured it was simple, but it was eluding me.

Comment: If you had in your HTML FORM `<input name="alpha[0]" onchange="calculateAlphaTotals()" />` and `<input name="alpha[1]" onchange="calculateAlphaTotals()" />` then you would have to use in JavaScript `document.myForm["alpha["+i+"]"].value` because for JavaScript `'alpha[0]'` and `'alpha[1]'` are just single form elements not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `document.myForm["alpha[]"][i].value` instead of `document.myForm["alpha["+i+"]"].value`

so you function will be like this

```
    function calculateAlphaTotals(){
        var length = document.myForm["alpha[]"].length;
        alert( length ); // correctly outputs 3
        for( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
            try{
                alert( document.myForm["alpha[]"][i].value ); // Object Required
            } catch( error ) { }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `index -[]` operator in the right place:

```
var x = document.myForm["alpha[]"];
for( var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ){
    var currentValue = x[i].value;
    alert(currentValue);
}
```

Yours: `document.myForm["alpha["+i+"]"]` changes the string, not iterate the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close, but you need to change one thing. `document.myForm["alpha[]"]` is actually an array, so if you want to cycle through it, you need to tack your `i` index on the end like this: `document.myForm["alpha[]"][i]`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
    function calculateAlphaTotals(){
        var els = document.myForm["alpha[]"];
        for(var i = 0, ceiling = els.length; i < ceiling; i++){
             alert(document.myForm["alpha[]"][i].value);
        }
    }
</script>
```